# SolR : full sentence spellcheck

Tags: solr, full-text-search, spell-checking

I'm trying to configure a spellchecker to autocomplete full sentences from my query.

I've already been able to get this results:

`"american israel" :

-> "american something"

-> "israel something"`

But i want :

`"american israel" :

-> "american israel something"`

This is my solrconfig.xml :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest_full" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
 <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">suggestTextFull</str>
 <lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest_full</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
  <str name="field">text_suggest_full</str>
  <str name="fieldType">suggestTextFull</str>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest_full" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
 <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
 <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest_full</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
 <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
 <str>suggest_full</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

And this is my schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="suggestTextFull" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">  
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>  
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>  
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">  
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>  
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>  
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

...

<field name="text_suggest_full" type="suggestTextFull" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

I've read somewhere that I have to use **spellcheck.q** because q use the WhitespaceAnalyzer, but when I use spellcheck.q i get a java.lang.NullPointerException

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If you spellcheck fields ( `text_suggest_full` ) contain `american something` and `israel something` so make sure, that there also exist an document/entry , with the value `american israel something`.

Solr will not  merge `american something` and `israel something` to one term and will not apply the result to your spellchecking for `american israel`.

Comment: Of course I have "american israel something" in one of my documents. That's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt be there an autocomplete approach more suitable? See [this](http://solr.pl/en/2010/10/18/solr-and-autocomplete-part-1/) article e.g.

Comment: I've already done an autocomplete function like this (actually, i've used this article to do it), but what I really want now is to match full sentences with my full query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the suggester / a flexible "autocomplete" component; 
you must have version 3.X of solr

**SolrConfig.xml :**

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
    <str name="field">name_autocomplete</str>
    </lst>
    </searchComponent>


    <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

**Shema.xml**

```
<field name="name_autocomplete" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

**Add copyField**

```
<copyField source="name" dest="name_autocomplete" />
```

**Reload solr, reindex all and test :** 
http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest?q=&amerspellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true

**Get something like :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="spellcheck">
    <lst name="suggestions">
      <lst name="ameri">
        <int name="numFound">2</int>
        <int name="startOffset">0</int>
        <int name="endOffset">2</int>
        <arr name="suggestion">
          <str>american morocco</str>
          <str>american morocco something</str>
        </arr>
      </lst>
      <str name="collation">american morocco something</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</response>
```

Hope that help

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, a problem with the spellcheck component is that each word is spell checked against the full index.
The "collation" of the spell checked words does not neccesary match an single document within the index, but might come from separate indexed documents.